# MySQL LIKE search from multi fields by PHP, PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the MySQL table that has filename and description fields.
Then, I wrote this code to do LIKE search.
However my poor code cannot conduct what I want to do.

Error message says

> Syntax error or access violation.

PHP 7.0 / MySQL 5.0.95 is my server's.

```
$keywords = str_replace( "\xc2\xa0", " ", $keywords );
$keywords = preg_replace("/[\s]+/", " ", trim($keywords));
$keywordsarray = array_unique(explode(' ', $keywords));
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM file_table WHERE ";

$sql2 = array();
$key = array();
foreach ($keywordsarray as $word) {
$sql2[] = " (filename LIKE ? OR describe LIKE ? )";
$key[] = '%'.$word.'%';
$key[] = '%'.$word.'%';
}
$builtsql = $sql1.implode(' AND ', $sql2);
$query = $db->prepare($builtsql);
$query->execute($key);
```

Could you give me good ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `$key` shouldn't be made part of the execute and doesn't use an argument neither.

Comment: I appreciate your kindly comment. Now I am re-writing code from first.

Comment: @Fred-ii- confused as to your comment on how it doesn't use an argument. The OP code pretty much follows the [example given on PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#example-1055). Main issue I see is the use of `describe` not being escaped as a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/describe.html

Comment: Dear Fred  Special thanks and I rewrote the code.
Then, I could get the Sql responses that I want.
In addition, thank you again for answering for my poor English sentences.

Comment: @fyrye ah yes, of course. That one eluded me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by not escaping the [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) `describe` in your query.

You should be able to resolve the Syntax error issue by wrapping the column name(s) in [identifier quotes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) (backtick).

```
$sql2[] = " (`filename` LIKE ? OR `describe` LIKE ? )";
```